# String treated like array inside loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have the following code:

```
for(i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++)
        {
            var reg = /\bSTEAM_[01]:[01]:[0-9]{1,10}\b/;
            var correctID = textArray[i].match(reg);

            if(correctID !== null)
            {
                var z = correctID.split(':');

                var correctID64 = '765611' + 97960265728 + z[3];

                steamIDs.push(correctID64);
                alert(correctID64);
            }
        };
```

However, I get an uncaught type error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'" when I try to split correctID. To my understanding, correctID should be a string, and when I try to dump an index of correctID, it fails. However, when I dump the data type it comes back with [Object Array].

Why is correctID getting treated like an array? I'm assigning it a new value each time the loop runs, not adding values to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.match()` function returns an array. [Here is reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp).

You may try:

```
var correctID = textArray[i].match(reg).toString();
```

or if you need just first occurence:

```
var correctID = textArray[i].match(reg)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`match()` returns an array containing all matches. It does *not* return a string.

[**Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)